# Do identity providers (Microsoft, Facebook, Twitter and Google) provide email addresses to web sites that use them for authentication?

Tags: facebook, authentication, azure, federated-identity

I am writing a mobile website that will be hosted in Windows Azure.

I already have a list of users with email addresses in my database and I am looking at how they will log in to my new website. This is a new service for existing users, they do not currently have a website login.

I note that azure supports using any of the following identity providers: Microsoft Account, Facebook login, Twitter login, Google login.

I'd like to user identity providers (Microsoft, Facebook, Twitter and Google) to authenticate people on my website, but this is only useful to me if the identity providers will provide me with an email address after they authenticate. This way I can match them up to an existing record in my database.

Will identity providers provide email addresses to web sites that use them for authentication as part of their IdP Token?

[image: ASP.NET Web Form Application with Federated Authentication]

Comment: I'm not sure if you're talking about using the Azure Mobile Services to perform the authentication, or Azure Access Control Service.  But even if you do get an email address back after authentication, what assurance do you have that it will map to one of the existing email addresses you have on record?  For example, I have multiple Live Ids, Google, Yahoo, FB, etc.  What are the chances that the single email address you have in your DB will match my authentication choice?

Comment: @ChrisW If the returned email address doesn't exist in our database, we will offer the user the ability to do a traditional registration by typing in their name and email address and send them a confirmation email.

Answer (score 2):

If using ACS, you should get back an email address claim for Google, Yahoo, and maybe the others - all except Live ID/Microsoft Account.

With Azure Mobile Services, I don't believe you get back the user's email address.  You get back a token that identifies the user, and you could use that to query the identity provider's (e.g. Google) API for the user's information.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx.